# Updating a list in a class, in a list

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x

In Python 3, I have a list of classes, and each class has a list in it. I'm having difficulties updating those lists. As so:

```
class Item():
    newPrice = 0
    prices = [0]
    def __init__(self, _prices):
        self.prices = _prices

items = [Item([10]), Item([20]), Item([30])]
for item in items:
    item.newPrice = SomeFunction()
    item.prices.append(item.newPrice)
```

The function `SomeFunction()` is an elaborate function that retrieves a different value for each `Item` instance.

For some reason, each `Item` instance in the `items` list has the same value for `prices`, which is a list that contains the `newPrice` value for each `Item` instance. I hope this is clear enough.

What am I missing?

Comment: You know, at first I didn't think so because I didn't quite understand what that poster was asking, but after reading Eugene's answer, it makes much more sense. You are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define prices as instance attribute, instead of class attribute, because class attributes are shared between all instances:

```
class Item():

    def __init__(self, _prices):
        self.newPrice = 0
        self.price = _prices
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I knew I was missing something. Thanks!